# ActiveAdmin set custom redirect path if not authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, activeadmin

I have a pritty simple custom Authorization but when it fails the user get redirected to what is set in active_admin.rb

```
config.root_to = 'dashboard#index'
```

and I have a redirect loop.

My only solution was to monkeypatch this line [ActiveAdmin::BaseController::Authorization](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/0fe85d7ad941e98462725c25cc8a0ebacb4467b1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb#L123)

with

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController < ::InheritedResources::Base
    module Authorization
      def redirect_backwards_or_to_root
        ActiveAdmin::Dependency.rails.redirect_back self, my_custom_authorize_failure_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

is there a prettier solution?

regards Kai

Answer (score -1):

```
config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
```

then in application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  protect_from_forgery 
  def access_denied(exception) 
    redirect_to define_your_path_here, alert: exception.message 
  end
end
```

Comment: no, since the ActiveAdmin BaseController is hardcoded to active_admin_root, which is a config variable, these don't help